# Keydown event doesn't work when the application is minimised to tray

Tags: python, wxpython, keydown, system-tray, trayicon

I have a very simple app whose task is to launch another subprocess once a user hits the key. However it is a bit complicated as the app must be minimised in the System tray. All works fine unless the app is minimised to the tray icon. The wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN just stops working. As i'm very new to Python and specifically to OOP I suspect I'm doing something wrong. Please advise how this can be fixed.

This is Windows app and there is no need to support the other systems. I tried keyboard listener from Pynput but it creates more problems with the multithreading. I would prefer to avoid using it.

```
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Title")

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.tbIcon = custTray.CustomTaskBarIcon(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ICONIZE, self.onMinimize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKeyPress)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(panel, 0, "Please wait.....")
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)

    def onKeyPress(self, event):
        pass
```

The result is that the event wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN works only when the form is NOT minimised. Once I minimise it the events stop working. I expect them to work as well when the app is minimised

Comment: it is natural behavior for all programs in all systems. When you minimise web browser or Excel (etc.) then system doesn't send key/mouse events to this program too.  It sends key/mouse events only to active/focused window. If you have two windows on screen then it sends only to active/focused window.

Comment: some GUI frameworks may have function to register global keys in system (hotkeys) - maybe this will help [wxPyWiki RegisterHotKey](https://wiki.wxpython.org/RegisterHotKey)

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works very well.